# Reload em Table HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde. Tenho uma table que carrego alguns equipamentos em HTML. Gostaria de recarrega-la ao excluir um equipamento da table.
Tenho a seguinte função no JavaScript da minha página. Essa função está no evento onClick do botão excluir.

```
function reloadNovoEquipamentoTable(){
      var element = document.getElementById('listNovoEquipamentosOrcamento');
      element.reload();}
```

Como fazer o reload dessa table?

### Ajax

```
function removeNovoEquipamento(equipamentoID, orcamentoID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "actions/removeNovoEquipamento",
        method: "POST",
        data: "equipamentoID=" + equipamentoID + "&orcamentoID=" + orcamentoID,
        success: function (response) {
            alert('excluido com sucesso');
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Segue abaixo a tabela para listar:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed margin-top" id="listNovoEquipamentosOrcamento">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-modal" data-target="#modalNovoEquipamento" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Novo Equipamento</button>
                                        <th colspan="10" style="text-align: center"><h3>Lista de Novos Equipamentos</h3></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Item</th>
                                            <th>Qtd.</th>
                                            <th>Descrição</th>
                                            <th id="td-acoes">Ações</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="tbody-novoEquipamento">

                                            <c:forEach items="${orcamento.listNovoEquipamentosOrcamento}" var="equipNovoOrcamento" varStatus="i">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        ${fn:length(orcamento.listEquipamentosOrcamento)+ i.index+1}
                                                        <input type="hidden" required="true" name="equipamentoNovoID" value="${equipNovoOrcamento.id}"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td><input id="qtd_${fn:length(orcamento.listEquipamentosOrcamento)+ i.index}" type="number" class="form-control" onchange="validaQuantidade(this);" value="${equipNovoOrcamento.quantidade}" placeholder="Qtd" min="1" required="true" name="quantidade"/></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="descricao" class="form-control" value="${equipNovoOrcamento.descricao}" readonly="true" /></td>                                                        
                                                    <td><button type="button" onclick='removeNovoEquipamento(${equipNovoOrcamento.id},${orcamento.id});reloadNovoEquipamentoTable();' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id='total' colspan='2'></td><td></td></tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

Comment: Como você exclui ? Por Ajax ?

Comment: Sim. Excluo via Ajax.

Comment: Então ao invés de dar reload na tabela porquê não apaga a linha ?

Comment: Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e posta o código ajax.

Comment: O que você usa para listar ? Uma tabela ?

Comment: Uso o <table></table>

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca um pouco da tabela...

Comment: O HTML, Mano....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira. Essa é a função JavaScript:

```
function reloadNovoEquipamentoTable(index) {
    $("#tbody-novoEquipamento tr:eq(" + index + ")").remove();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Troca o seguinte:

```
<button type="button" onclick='removeNovoEquipamento(${equipNovoOrcamento.id},${orcamento.id});
        reloadNovoEquipamentoTable();' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
```

Por isso:

```
<button type="button" data-equipamentoid="${equipNovoOrcamento.id}" 
          data-orcamentoid="${orcamento.id}" 
          class="btn btn-danger btn-sm bt-remover-equipamento">
```

E faz um handler pro click a partir da classe `bt-remover-equipamento`, que exclui a linha em caso de sucesso:

```
$('.bt-remover-equipamento').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var equipamentoID = $this.data('equipamentoid');
  var orcamentoID = $this.data('orcamentoid');
  $.ajax({
    url: "actions/removeNovoEquipamento",
    method: "POST",
    data: "equipamentoID=" + equipamentoID + "&orcamentoID=" + orcamentoID,
    success: function (response) {
        $this.parents('tr').remove();
        alert('excluido com sucesso');
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Talvez precise de alguns ajustes (é bem provável), mas a ideia geral é essa.